# Java: Show "*.java" in "File of type" as default in fileChooser

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser

I have one problem in fileChooser.

when fileChooser window come then I want to show .java as a default name in "File of type" and in list I want to show  *.java, *.class, All File respectively.

For this I use following code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] argv) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(new File("."));
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new MyFilter());
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new MyFilter2());
fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
System.out.println(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
}
}

class MyFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
public boolean accept(File file) {
String filename = file.getName();
return filename.endsWith(".java");
}

public String getDescription() {
return "*.java";
}
}

class MyFilter2 extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
  public boolean accept(File file) {
    String filename = file.getName();
    return filename.endsWith(".class");
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return "*.class";
  }
}
```

but in this code by default nothing is there in "File of type" and in the list it show  *.java, *.class, All File respectively.But I want to show *.java name as a default name in "File of type".

When I change this code and put **fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);** above to **fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new MyFilter());** then All File show defaule name in "File of type".

If you save a text file in text editor then there **Text Documents(*.txt)*** show as a default and in list Text Documents(.txt) and All File is there.

I want same thing in my application.

I am also attaching photo which give clear information what I want:

My application work like this:

[image]

[image]

But I want like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Customizing a JFileChooser](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CustomizingaJFileChooser.htm) might be worth looking at as it does exactly as you describe.

[The official JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) documentation also covers your problem.

Comment: the exact answer is using the function fileChooser.setFileFilter just before opening the fileChooser dialog. see suggestions below

Answer (score 3):

Try in this way :

```
JFileChooser fS = new JFileChooser();
fS.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
fS.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
fS.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(wordExtDesc, ".class"));
fS.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(excelExtDesc, ".java"));
```

Inverting the order of the filter set, the last filter added should appear as the default ...

Comment: should be "class" and "java" (without dot)

Answer (score 1):

If you call this after adding all your filters and setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed, then All files is selected by default:

```
fileChooser.setFileFilter(fileChooser.getChoosableFileFilters()[2]);
```

Of course choose the correct index to have the one you want selected by default

Comment: thanx ..I use this code, one problem is there, it show *.java as a default name but when I select "My Computer" or "My Documents" then it not display any thing.

Comment: sorry, I don't have that behaviour on Win7 so I cannot try to find a solution for that. May be it is a bug in the JFileChooser, I don't know.

Comment: Downvoter, would you care to explain? (especially on an issue that over 6 months old)

Answer (score 1):

My way:

```
//set default dir to user home
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home"));
//items in filter dropdown box
FileFilter excelType = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel spreadsheet (.xls)", "xls");
FileFilter wordType = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Word document (.doc)", "doc");
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(excelType);
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(wordType);
//default (initial) filter predefined in dropdown box
fileChooser.setFileFilter(excelType);
//initial file name
fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("report"));
//clear "All files" from dropdown filter box
fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
//open filechooser dialog
int response = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
if(response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
    //do somethink...
}
```